# How to access invisible Unordered List element with Selenium WebDriver using Java

Tags: java, select, selenium, selenium-webdriver, html-lists

This is the HTML code:

```
<ul id="personalBar">
    <li id="upload" style="display:none;"></li>
    <li id="personal">
        <span class="translate"></span>
        <span id="userName">qaadmin</span>
        <div id="dropDownArrow"></div>
        <ul>
            <li id="pendingActivities" class="translate" onclick="eCommon.helper.viewAllPendingActivities()" translatekey="MANAGE_STORE">Manage Store</li>
            <li class="translate" onclick="eCommon.helper.outSourceViewReports()" translatekey="UM_REPORT_MENU">Reports</li>
            <li id="learnMore" class="translate" onclick="eCommon.helper.outSourceLearnMore()" translatekey="BANNER_THIRD_MSG">Learn more about einstein™</li>
            <li id="DownloadEinstein" class="translate" onclick="eCommon.helper.outSourceLearnMore()" translatekey="BANNER_FOURTH_MSG">Download the einstein™ World app.</li>
            <li class="translate" onclick="location.reload();" translatekey="CREATE_EINSTEIN_ACIVITIES">Create einstein™ Activities</li>
            <li class="translate" onclick="eCommon.helper.outSourceGetEinsteinActivities()" translatekey="GET_EINSTEIN_ACTIVITIES">Get einstein™ Activities</li>
            <li class="translate" onclick="eCommon.helper.outSourceManageYourEinsteinAccount()" translatekey="MANAGE_YOUR_EINSTEIN_ACCOUNT">Manage your einstein™ Account</li>
            <li id="logOut" class="translate" onclick="am.UserManagement.doLogOut(false)" translatekey="LOGOUT">Logout</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The amount of items in the list varies according to users privileges so each element number in the list is not fixed.

The list is normally closed and it is opened only by clicking on it.
So:

```
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("personalBar")));
dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Get einstein™ Activities");
```

Presents error:

> org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "ul"

When trying this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[contains(text(),'Manage your einstein™ Account')][@class='translate']")).click();
```

It fails with:

> org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following should help -

```
driver.findElement(By.id("personal")).findElement(By.id("dropDownArrow")).click();  
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[contains(text(),'Manage your einstein™ Account')][@class='translate']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you cannot approach `ul -> li` with the `Select` abstraction - it was designed to work with `select -> option`.

You second approach fails since **you first need to click on `ul` to open up the list**:

```
WebElement personalList = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("ul#personalBar li#personal ul"));
personalList.click();

personalList.findElement(By.xpath("//li[contains(text(),'Manage your einstein™ Account')][@class='translate']")).click();
```

This is the general idea - first open up the list, then click an item - I might not be accurate in the code and details since I cannot reproduce the problem and test the proposal.

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

Comment: @Eliyahu it could be that you need to first click the outer `ul`: `driver.findElement(By.id("personalBar")).click();`.

Comment: Thank you @alecxe! I will think about both these answers some more, but currently I accept the second one

Comment: @Eliyahu sure, this is not a problem at all. What is important is that you've solved it here and you've learned something new. I would've upvoted Vikas's answer if it would contain not only the code, but some more explanation about the options you've tried and about the one that was proposed in the answer. (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques) Happy seleniuming!

Comment: I agree with you. You described much more but your answer didn't work (as is) while his did. Again, I'll read it again tomorrow, now it is almost midnight here, my brain system is shutting down ;)

Comment: I agree with you @alecxe, will try to be more elaborate in future :)

Answer (score -1):

If there are three cascading `div`s then the code to locate works like this:

First locate main `div` by id `BodyContainer` then locate unordered list by id `connectionParent` then locate list by id `divAddNewGroup_0` then locate my required button(+) using `By.xpath`:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("BodyContainer"))
      .findElement(By.id("connectionParent"))
      .findElement(By.id("divAddNewGroup_0"))
      .findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='divAddNewGroup_0']/span[1]/i"))
      .click();
```

Comment: There is already an accepted answer and "divAddNewGroup_0" is not defined in the sample code in the question.